# CAS and SAML 2.0 Implementation in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, single-sign-on, cas, saml-2.0

We have requirement on our project wherein we need to authenticate users using the client's CAS implementation over the SAML 2.0 protocol.

We found a number of Apache Modules, which achieve this purpose, but we are using Nginx, and cannot use them.

We also found a library called Pac4J which supports CAS with SAML 1.1, but it seems like it does not have support for SAML 2.0.

If you have experiences or ideas with any such libraries, please let us know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're open to using a SaaS offering to integrate with to provide your SP SAML use case check out [PingOne APS](https://www.pingone.com/#developer) from Ping Identity [Note: I work for Ping]. Adds SAML 1.1/2.0 to your application via a RESTful API integration and no toolkits to mess around with so you can guarantee your SAML is secure and compliant. Usually takes 1/2 day to integrate completely.

HTH -- 
Ian

Comment: Although our team will probably not be okay with using a SaaS offering, I'm accepting this answer because technically it does answer the question, and at this point there are no better answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of pac4j. At that time, there is supports for the OpenID/OAuth/CAS protocols and it's available in several environments: J2E, Spring Security, Shiro, Play framework... See http://www.pac4j.org for a better understanding...

<del>There is currently no support for SAML 1.1/2.0 but it's on my internal roadmap. Just let me know if you are interested to work on that and require my help...</del>

Supported protocols are:

- OAuth (1.0 & 2.0)
- CAS (1.0, 2.0, SAML, logout & proxy)
- HTTP (form & basic auth authentications)
- OpenID
- SAML (2.0)
- Google App Engine UserService
- OpenID Connect 1.0

[source](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j#externalstateful-authentication-protocols)

Comment: Could you please tell me which exact versions of SAML do you support ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear : at the moment, NONE ! But I plan to add both supports : SAML 1.1 and 2.0. The idea was to join our efforts...